# Creating a search that you can click a link to open a form from it's unique ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, uniqueidentifier

Ok, so I'm currently using the following code to implement my search:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionstringexample %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [SPECIALIST], [CUST_LNAME], [CUST_FNAME], [COMPANY_NAME], [EVENT_TYPE] FROM [tblcontacts] WHERE (([CUST_FNAME] = @CUST_FNAME) OR ([CUST_LNAME] = @CUST_LNAME) OR ([COMPANY_NAME] = @COMPANY_NAME) OR ([EVENT_TYPE] = @EVENT_TYPE))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchtext" Name="CUST_FNAME" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchtext" Name="CUST_LNAME" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchtext" Name="COMPANY_NAME" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchtext" Name="EVENT_TYPE" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="recordsgrid" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    Width="916px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" 
            BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" 
                SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SPECIALIST" HeaderText="Event Specialist" 
                SortExpression="SPECIALIST" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CUST_LNAME" HeaderText="Client's Last Name" 
                SortExpression="CUST_LNAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CUST_FNAME" HeaderText="Client's First Name" 
                SortExpression="CUST_FNAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="COMPANY_NAME" HeaderText="Company Name" 
                SortExpression="COMPANY_NAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EVENT_TYPE" HeaderText="Event Type" 
                SortExpression="EVENT_TYPE" />

        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4b6c9e" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

What I want is to be able to click on the ID in the ID column and have that open up a new page that auto fills the data of the form correlating to that unique ID. I'm using asp.net and C#. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT:***

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Searchresults.aspx?@ID={0}" Text="ID" DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" HeaderText="ID" 
                SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False"  />
```

Comment: Replace the bound field with a hyperlink field. Make the navigateURL somepage.aspx?ID=......  and then parse the query string. -- Sorry, no time for a proper answer, but that should get you started. I can't recall at the moment if you need to make it a template field or not.

Comment: That get's me started, though I was looking that option and I read somewhere that you can't pass more than like two fields or something? Is that true?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You want to search by ID? Isn't that one field?

Comment: I wanted to search the database by allowing the user to type in any of the data in the Boundfield's above (ex. First name, last name, ... etc), when the results show, I want to allow them to click on the ID of each result as a link, that'll take them to a new page with the form and all the data associated with it. I'm not sure how much that makes sense, but I'll try some of the things you mentioned and everyone and come back with some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hyperlink column that links to a page passing a query parameter that contains that rows ID.  The hyperlink column allows you to specify a url format string and then use data from the datasource in that string.  Once you're on another page with the proper ID I'm sure you can populate that form with the correct data.

Comment: I've edited my question to show you the hyperlink I'm using, but how do I get the ID in the url to load into the ID say on a gridview on my "searchresults.aspx" page?

Comment: @Kruce I don't think you want the '@' symbol in the url, you probably want to remove it.  On the code of the search result page you can use `Request.QueryString["ID"]` to get the ID passed in.  I'm assuming you know how to write a query against your database to get a row by ID.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've got something working and I'm using formview to view results allowing them to edit! Thank you for the "Request.QueryString"! :)

Answer (score 1):

you could make the ID column into an itemtemplate:

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>' CommandName="detail" commandArgument="<%$ Eval("id")%> />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

then in the click event of your gridview, you can access the ID that has been clicked and you can pass that id to whatever method you have to load the correlating data.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.CommandName ="detail")
     {
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  List<Something> test = SomeMethod(index);
    }
 }
```

edit: and as some have suggested already, you could just use a hyperlink with navigate to aswell.